# Sending UDP from one computer to another in python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a pretty standard simple demo for udp packets but I get an error when trying to send to another IP address and I don't really understand why.

> socketerror: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

The code that I thought would work is basically....

Server

```
def Main():
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 20030

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))

    #Then it prints incoming data and sends it back to client.
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.close()
```

Client

```
def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 20020

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    server = ('10.20.64.115', 20030)

    #loop for input to send to server.
    s.sendto(message, server)
    s.close()
```

If I run them both on the same computer and host = 127.0.0.1 on both, both are bound to 127.0.0.1 and s.sendto(message, server) is sending to 127.0.0.1 they can send messages back and for without problems.

If I run them on different computers I believe I'm supposed to use the client to sendto the IP address of the server's IP address but I get the [Errno 22].

So I tried binding the client to 192.0.0.1 that gave an [Errno 99] cannot assign requested address.

I tried binding the client to 0.0.0.0 and the sendto address to 10.20.64.115 but the client just returns to a new line and the server doesn't see anything.

All the tutorials say to bind and sendto 127.0.0.1 so I set both computers to that and it also doesn't show up in the server.

So I'm all confused now. Correct any misunderstandings...

bind(ip address you want to listen to, port you want to listen to)

sendto(message, ip address you want to send to, port you want to send to)

0.0.0.0 is listening to everything.

192.0.0.1 is listening to the router.

127.0.0.1 is listening to just the computer.

If so what ip address do I need to sendto to avoid an errno 22 and successfully send the message to the server? Or am I missing something with the sockets?

Comment: which line of your code is generating the error? Is this python 2 or python 3? What is the value of `message` when you get the error?

Comment: @jJames K Polk The line sendto in the client gets the error. Both are using version 2.7. The value of message is usually just a string with a few characters. "test" or something similar.

Comment: You totally lost point! `UDP Server use 2 port` first listen second for sending. On your code serveron  port = 20030 and client port = 20020, where connect/serve ?

Answer (score -1):

> bind(ip address you want to listen to, port you want to listen to)

While sending UDP packets, on the client side, it does not require `bind()` to attach its socket to an address, you can directly use `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` to send and receive messages from the server. Refer [here](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/udp.html) for more details

Comment: I don't think so. I deleted the bind and just used the sendto. It doesn't give me errno 22 but it skips to the next line and the message being sent never shows up in the server.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I just realized when it is skipping to the next line it's not broken or getting an error it is waiting for the server to respond. Part of my loop that I didn't include is that the server sends the message back. So the errno 22 isn't an issue in this case but the message never gets to the server and that is what I'm trying to solve. But I see the point that the binding in the client isn't the issue. So the errno 22 is probably not really an issue. It is an issue of what IP address to sendto. I still don't understand what is going on though.

Comment: @JamesKPolk it partly solves it, now he knows its not a binding issue, which was his assumption before like he mentioned.